# Show uGet downloader window with click on tray-icon or shortcut

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I like [uGet multi-thread downloader](https://askubuntu.com/a/557064/47206) in Linux. I use it with Flashgot addon in Firefox. But I miss the following feature: when it is minimized to tray, the only way I can make it visible is by right clicking the tray icon and than selecting from a long list the option 'Show window'. Ideally, it should be showing by left or middle clicking the tray icon, but it doesn't. I have tested this in different Linux desktops.

Can I make a shortcut for "show window" feature?

---

UPDATE:

This is desktop-specific. In KDE the menu is triggered with right-click, in Xfce with left-click (tested in Mint).

I can confirm that the intended feature is already active at least in some desktops. For example, in Fluxbox (Manjaro).

Comment: @Michael Tunnell - help!

Answer (score 1):

Try launching the application again.  If that causes it to display, then simply assign a keyboard shortcut to the application launcher however your desktop environment does that.

If not, then if uGet has DBUS support, you might be able to do it through DBUS.  `qdbus` is your friend here.

If not, then you probably can't do it without modifying the source code.  Guess you could send in a feature request.

Comment: It depends on the desktop. It works in Xfce exactly as you described it. In KDE starting a new instance doesn't bring the window forth and in fact launches a secondary running event in the system monitor that KSysGuard calls 'zombie' :)  -- More info on `qdbus` would be greatly appreciated. - Finding a command for that window to open would do it.

Comment: should I find `uget-gtk` in the list of `qdbus` when uget is running?

Comment: @cipricus It's strange that the behavior differs between Xfce and KDE.  Perhaps something is wrong or incomplete with your installation of KDE.  Make sure all of the packages are installed that are required (or even recommended) by the KDE metapackage in your distro.  You should also investigate how the new instance is being launched; perhaps Xfce is using a different command line or a different `.desktop` launcher file.  Try running simply `/usr/bin/uget` or whatever from a terminal and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Re: `qdbus`, explaining how to use D-Bus is out-of-scope for this, especially not knowing whether uGet even supports it.  Google for `qdbus tutorial`, and also look at `qdbusviewer` for a GUI version.  And finally, you might want to talk to the uGet devs or file a bug report about the varying behavior or lack of the feature.